# apply arguments to wordpress function wp_dropdown_pages()

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I format the arguments code in wordpress functions?

I'm trying to apply the `child_of`, `314` to  `wp_dropdown_pages()` so that I can set the dropdown to be limited to the children of the host page as a sort of filter.

I have tried `wp_dropdown_pages('child_of', 314)`, `wp_dropdown_pages(child_of, 314)`, `wp_dropdown_pages('child_of' , '314')` but none of them seemed to do anything.

Am I just overthinking this? Am I missing that all important semi-colon?

The shortcode is just a substitute for  tags for use in widget aware areas without full php tag support.

I used [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) to figure out its parameters, but I do not know how to apply the parameters :(

```
<li id="states">
    <form action="[insert_php] bloginfo('url'); [/insert_php]" method="get">
        [insert_php] wp_dropdown_pages('child_of', '314'); [/insert_php]<br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li id="states">
    <form action="[insert_php] bloginfo('url'); [/insert_php]" method="get">

        [insert_php] 

            $myargs = array( 'child_of' => 314, );

            wp_dropdown_pages($myargs);

        [/insert_php]

        <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">

    </form>
</li>
```

*i hope it works for you, thanks !*

Comment: Thanks man! I was under the assumption that the variables were already defined in some wordpress function core file somewhere. It works as intended!